# A player to skip combat phase in Two-Headed Giant

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-two-headed-giant

What happens if a particular player is said to skip his/her combat phase in a Two-Headed Giant game (for instance, if someone had cast [Moment of Silence](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=19554))?

Is the whole team unable to attack, or is only that particular player unable to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If an effect causes a player to skip a step, phase, or turn, that player’s team does so.

Similarly, if an effect gives a player an extra turn or adds a phase or a step to that player’s turn, that player’s team takes the extra turn, phase, or step.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Were you quoting the rulebook?

Comment: Oh, and btw, what if instead of the wording "skip phase", it is said "target player can't attack this turn", would then the outcome be different? (I'm not sure if such card exists though)

Comment: **805.8.** If an effect gives a player an extra turn or adds a phase or step to that player’s turn, that player’s team takes the extra turn, phase, or step. If an effect causes a player to skip a step, phase, or turn, that player’s team does so. If a single effect causes more than one player on the same team to add or skip the same step, phase, or turn, that team adds or skips only that step, phase, or turn. If an effect causes a player to control another player, the controller of that effect controls the affected player’s team.

Comment: @Kira I guess the answer to that would depend on the exact wording, but I think it'd be player-specific most of the time. Technically, only creatures attack, players just declare attackers. If the text said "target player can't declare attackers this turn", it would only affect the one targeted player.

Comment: I think for an effect like that, the card would say "Creatures target player controls can't attack this turn."

Comment: Makes some strange games with the new Emrakul.

Answer (score 9):

The whole team is affected, according to rule 805.8 as of the 28 August 2016 revision of the comprehensive rules:

> 805.8. If an effect gives a player an extra turn or adds a phase or step to that player’s turn, that player’s team takes the extra turn, phase, or step. **If an effect causes a player to skip a step, phase, or turn, that player’s team does so.** If a single effect causes more than one player on the same team to add or skip the same step, phase, or turn, that team adds or skips only that step, phase, or turn. If an effect causes a player to control another player, the controller of that effect controls the affected player’s team.

(emphasis added)